# Magento 2 - Cart - Cache issue

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

We've created an extension that sets a default shipping method for the cart. Below $50 the shipping costs will be $5,95, above $50 the shipping will be free.

The function itself works fine, but the problem is that the amount for shipping seems to be cached (different than other cart totals).

If I have a product that costs $19,95, add this to my cart, and in my cart set the quantity on 4, free shipping should be shown. All totals are updated, only the shipping still shows the $5,95. After I refresh the page again, the shipping cost is update to 'Free'.

How can I prevent this cache?

This is the cart: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qr9nxrrqidnp4n/Schermafbeelding%202017-08-30%20om%2011.28.54.png?dl=0

Comment: The mini cart or cart page?

Comment: The cart page itself

Comment: This may be a stupid question but when writing your module did you take into account the price x qty when creating your rule if not then it wont see the criteria as being met